# android: How to access Views of a newly used layout in the current layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am unable to tackle this familiar scenario.

In my project, i am using ActionBarSherlock and on `Search icon` clicked i am replacing the ActionBar with a custom layout. The problem is how can i get the Views for onClickListener and all from this new layout?

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
        .setActionView(R.layout.on_search_icon_clicked)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS |MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
        return true;
}

my on_search_icon_clicked.xml is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_image"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

now how to get this `search_image.setOnClickListener` and all?

it says `NullPointerException` if i am using this in my onCreate.

Thank You

Comment: inflate the view, add the listener and pass the view to menu builder instead of the layout id

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView%28android.view.View%29

instead of

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView%28int%29

Comment: but there are 2 view to be shown. EditText and an Image. Thats why i was using Layout ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean inflate the layout, something like

```
LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.on_search_icon_clicked, null, false);
view.findViewById(R.id.search_image).setOnClickListener(...);
menu.setActionView(view);
```

I think you can get the inflater also by calling  getLayoutInflater();

Comment: looks good. But it didn't work :(. I added the code in my question. But i am not getting any toast :(

Comment: hmm this makes no much sense for me, but I've not directly tested similar situation, try to debug the app placing a breakpoint into onClick()

Comment: I think you can also avoid the inflater stuff by later calling getActionView() after passing a layoutid to setActionView

Comment: something like this?: "EditText et = (EditText) menu.getItem(1).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.search_editText);"

Comment: MenuItem item = menu.add("Search")
item.setActionView().setxxx etc, then item.getActionView()

Comment: i have 1 little problem. so when i click on searchIcon i get this layout with editText n ImageView. when i click on the EditText it opens softkeyboard, then when i click device back button to dismiss softkeyboard it disappears. the problem is it never open when i click on the EditText from the next time. why is this so?

Comment: Are you overriding onclick on edittext? I think you dont' need that

Comment: no i am not overriding.if you see in my layout. I have singleline = "true" for my EditText. Even this attribute is not working, i can still see the "Enter" like key on the softkeyboard

Comment: I'm not sure but you may encounter same problem described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258962/actionbarsherlock-actionbar-disappears-when-focus-changes-from-edittext-to-butto