# Android action bar disappearing after keyboard close

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Here's how the situation looks like.
[image]

And my layout file is like:

```
<RelativeLayout>  # Parent
  <RelativeLayout> # Camera preview
  </RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLayout>   # Bottom bar
  </LinearLayout>
</RealtiveLayout>
```

I understand Android adds/removes views by evaluating whether they are within the view area but I haven't been able to fix this by any means so far.

Using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to ensure Actionbar is always visible isn't doable as that spoils the aspect ratio of camera preview above.

Comment: Where did you define your action bar settings ?

Comment: Didn't define anything specific. Do I have to?

Comment: Try to set one, to modify parameters and check if it sill happens. Also, look if there is a similar known issue : I spotted people complaining about actionbar going black when maps api is used. Check for it because I think both the Maps api and a camera preview are using surface view .

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

See [ActionBarSherlock actionbar disappears when focus changes from EditText to Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258962/actionbarsherlock-actionbar-disappears-when-focus-changes-from-edittext-to-butto)

For those of you who can't switch to `adjustResize`.
I noticed that actionbar is reappearing after the screen is turned off and on again, so I solved it with this hack:

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(dialog1 -> {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
        }, 600);
    }
})
```

This code requests redraw of the whole hierarchy approximately after the keyboard has settled. The checked SDK version and the delay value may be lower, but I decided to play safe.